# LAVA neuromorphic computing run model runs indefinetly

Tags: neural-network, intel, lava

I am trying to run a python code for deploying a network into a intel loihi2 chip. Im using LAVA framework for the deployment, but for some reason my code always gets stuck in the part where it runs the network.

I have let it run for hours and hours, but it never ends. Anybody know how con I solve that? I have a computer with i5 10th generation 1.10GHz. Is it a problem of velocity of the computer?

Thank you a lot in advance!

Im trying this code, which is an example of the documentation posted on their GitHub.

```
from lava.magma.core.run_conditions import RunSteps
from lava.magma.core.run_configs import Loihi1SimCfg
# Import monitoring Process.
from lava.proc.monitor.process import Monitor

# Configurations for execution.
num_steps = 1
rcfg = Loihi1SimCfg(select_tag='rate_neurons')
run_cond = RunSteps(num_steps=num_steps)

# Instantiating network and IO processes.
network_balanced = EINetwork(**network_params_balanced)
state_monitor = Monitor()

state_monitor.probe(target=network_balanced.state,  num_steps=num_steps)

# Run the network.
#Here is where it gets stuck...
network_balanced.run(run_cfg=rcfg, condition=run_cond)
states_balanced = state_monitor.get_data()[network_balanced.name][network_balanced.state.name]
network_balanced.stop()
```